# Form doesn't send email to some addresses

Tags: php, forms

I'm having a problem with my simple form script which always send to my previous email address, now doesn't send to my new one. Is it because there's a dash in the address? Here's the script:

```
<?php 

if ($_POST["email"] <> '') {
    $ToEmail = 'info@xxx-xxx.com';
    $EmailSubject = 'Site contact form '; 
    $mailheader = "From: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
    $mailheader .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["email"]."\r\n"; 
    $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY = "Name: ".$_POST["name"]."<br>"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Email: ".$_POST["email"]."<br>"; 
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Telephone: ".$_POST["tel"]."<br>";
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Type: ".$_POST["type"]."<br>";
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Subject: ".$_POST["subject"]."<br>";
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Hours per week: ".$_POST["hours"]."<br>";
    $MESSAGE_BODY .= "Additional information: ".nl2br($_POST["info"])."<br>"; 

    // HAS THE SPAM TRAP FIELD BEEN FILLED IN?

    if( !empty( $_POST['random'] ) )
    {exit;}

    mail($ToEmail, $EmailSubject, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die ("Failure"); 

?> 

<html>

    <h3>Thank you for your email</h3>
    <h4>I'll get back to you as soon as possible</h4>
    <a href="index.html"><p>Click here to go back to the home page</p></a>

</html>


<?php 
} else { 
?> 

<html>Sorry, this form didn't work</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Do you get an error, or does the mail not arrive?

Comment: Have you checked the JUNK folder for your e-mail address? Can you look at the SMTP logs for your mailer daemon?

Comment: I don't get an error but the mail doesn't arrive, thanks

Comment: sorry how would i look at the mailer logs? thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is probably getting caught in a spam filter on the receiving end. Add the sender email address in your script to your new email's white list and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, it's not in the spam folder. Normal emails from the same address I used for the form gets through fine

Answer (score 0):

Did you migrate from a Gmail to a Yahoo account? The dash should not make any difference. Certain email providers (esp. Yahoo) have problems with emails being sent using the mail command.

Comment: Thanks. It's a new domain and I transferred the domain to a gmail apps account, but it's strange as I have another google apps account which receives the mail

Comment: are your MX records set up correct? Is Email section functioning properly in Google App setup?

Comment: I copied the MX records from the other apps account, so should be ok? The account is sending and receiving email fine...

Comment: Just checked one of the settings and it seems there is still a temporary email address? When I used that in the form, presto I get the mail! Yet normal email works on the non-temporary address... Now to figure out how to make address permanent!